# Is there a way to integrate Trust wallet in React.js without WalletConnect?

Tags: reactjs, mobile, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

I know we can connect our Dapp with Trust wallet using WalletConnect.
But I want to place the Trust wallet Connect button separately from WalletConnect.
Is there a way to connect Dapp with Trust wall without using WalletConnect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [solana wallet adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter), if you're using solana blockchain)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).